# Dataflow jobs are failed due to Beam-nuggets referencing to sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have created an ETL in GCP which reads data from MySQL and migrates it to BigQuery. To read data from MySQL, we use beam-nuggets library. This library is passed as an extra package ('--extra_package=beam-nuggets-0.17.1.tar.gz') to the dataflow job. Cloud functions were used to create the dataflow job. The code was working fine and the Dataflow job got created and the data migration was successful.

After the latest version of sqlalchemy – 1.4 got released, we were unable to deploy the cloud function. The cloud function deployment failed with the exception as mentioned below.

[image]

To fix this issue, we tried to give the previous version of sqlalchemy – 1.3.23 in the requirements.txt file of cloud functions. This resolved the issue and the cloud functions got deployed successfully. But when we triggered the dataflow job from cloud functions, we got the same error as mentioned above.
This issue is caused because beam-nuggets library is internally referencing sqlalchemy during the run time and the job fails with the same error. Is it possible to manually enforce beam-nuggets to pick a specific version of sqlalchemy??

Comment: Can you share code .. or piece of code which you feel  can be causing problem.

Comment: Also, could you please add your error message inline as text rather than a link to a png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing a specific version of sqlalchemy via the `extra_package` flag as well.

Comment: How can we add more than one package in extra_package?

Comment: You can specify this option multiple times: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.28.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L1031